# selecting public repo in ambari cluster install wizard

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I am getting the following error while trying to select HDP2.2 as shown in the picture below.

[image]

I am able to do zypper and wget operations, any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the proxy info to the configuration solved this issue.